# How to disable Flash games in Excel 2003?

Tags: flash, microsoft-excel-2003

Some students in my college computer lab are playing Flash games that have been embedded in Excel 2003 spreadsheets. How can I disable Flash being used in this way in Excel 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling ActiveX controls in the spreadsheets will disable flash from playing.

UPDATE added details on how:
For Office 2003, there is no "Trust Center" to allow you to do this. However, there are registry settings that allow this lockdown. Setting permissions on these registry keys will then prevent them from being changed back.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben%2Dus%3B827742